# Unit Matrices for $M_n(M_n(\mathbb{R}))$

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-computation

In the case of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ we can define unit matrices $E_{ij}$ in the following way,

$$E_{ij}f_l = \delta_{lj}f_i$$

where the $\{f_i\}$ is a basis for our space.  One consequence of this definition is that the $(i,j)$ element of $E_{ij}$ is $1$ and everything else is $0$; additionally

$$E_{ij}E_{lk} = \delta_{jl} E_{ik}$$

.... okay, anyway I'm not sure how unit matrices look in $M_n(M_n):=M_n(M_n(\mathbb{R}))$.
And how do the above properties carry over?

Also, I don't understand why the following line in a proof is true (as per the above):
Consider $P=(E_{ij}) \in M_n(M_n)$.  Then $P=P^\dagger$, and 
$$P^2 =  (\sum_{k=1}^n E_{ik}E_{kj})(nE_{ij}) = nP$$

Comment: If $M_n$ means $n\times n$ matrices and we think of this as a vector space, then the operators on this will be represented as $n^2\times n^2$ matrices.  So, don't you want $M_{n^2}(M_n)$?

Comment: You are correct with the definition of $M_n$. But I think you are incorrect to give $M_{n^2}(M_n)$....   Although I see why you should think this.  The space $M_n(M_n)$ is isomorphic to $M_{n^2}$ in the very natural way; every element of $M_n(M_n)$ is a matrix of dimension n (that's the part on the outside) whose field is matrices of dimension n (that's the inner part).  So that's a matrix space with entries which are matrices!  :o)

Comment: I worry about your use of the word "natural" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have tagged your question with quantum computation. So perhaps you may find it more intuitive if we work in Dirac notation. That is we let $\{| j \rangle\}$ be an orthonormal basis for the underlying vector space (so that $\langle i|j\rangle =\delta_{i,j}$).  Then what you call the unit matrices are equivalent defined as
$$
E_{i,j} = |i\rangle\!\langle j|.
$$
That is, they have a 1 in the entry at the $i$'th row and $j$'th column and zeros everywhere else.  Now the set of matrices $\{|E_{i,j}\rangle\!\rangle \}$ form an orthonormal basis for the vector space of matrices, where the inner product between two matrices $A$ and $B$ is $$\langle\!\langle A|B\rangle\!\rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(A^\dagger B).
$$

We can now play the same trick.  Define the "super" unit matrices as 
$$
F_{i,j;k,l} = |E_{i,j}\rangle\!\rangle\!\langle\!\langle E_{k,l}|.
$$
Then, the $F$ matrices satisfy the same properties as the $E$ matrices.

From your last sentence, however, it does not seem like you are interested in these unit matrices.  Your final equation suggests the matrix you define as $P$ is simply the matrix of 1's in every entry.  This can be written
$$
P = \sum_{i,j} E_{i,j}.
$$
Then direct calculation leads to
$$
P^\dagger = \sum_{i,j} E_{i,j}^\dagger = \sum_{i,j} E_{j,i} = P,
$$
and
$$
P^2 = \sum_{i,j,k,l} E_{i,j}E_{k,l} = \sum_{i,j,k,l} E_{i,l}\delta_{j,k} = n \sum_{i,l} E_{i,l} = n P.
$$

Comment: Excellent response! Cool notation... is the super dirac symbol something of standard notation?  Either way, I feel tempted to start using it!

Comment: It's probably the most common but I wouldn't call it standard yet.  Some also use a round bracket, $| A)$, to distinguish them.  Of course, the closer one is to mathematics on the mathematical physics spectrum, the more likely it is to not use Dirac notation at all I've found.

Comment: I suppose the first conclusion is that the original post was wrong (i.e. the source was a typo... hence I was stuck).  As I wrote it, it was 
$(\sum_{k=1} E_{ik}E_{kj})(nE_{ij}) = (\sum_{k=1} \delta_{kk} E_{ij})(nE_{ij}) = (nE_{ij})(nE_{ij}) = n^2E^2_{ij} = \delta_{ij} n^2 E_{ii}$
My professor gave me a set of notes on q. computation/info but also told me there are several typos scattered throughout...  This must have been one!

Comment: I think if you just put an "=" between $(\sum E_{ik}E_{kj})=nE_{ij}$, that should do it.